# Create instance of class by calling method, without new keyword

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I want to create a new object of Abc.MainClass by calling function Abc.MainClass.callMainClass() from another class (Abc.CallingClass). I don't want to use the new keyword there.

Here is the Abc.MainClass:

```
goog.provide('Abc.MainClass');

Abc.MainClass.callMainClass = function() {
    var config = null;
    return new Abc.MainClass(config);
}

Abc.MainClass= function(config) {
}
```

Here is the Abc.CallingClass:

```
goog.require('Abc.MainClass');

this.mainClass = Abc.MainClass.callMainClass;
this.mainClass();
```

Of course it doesn't work. Do you know why it is wrong? How should I implement such thing?

Comment: Have you tried Object.create(classname)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will do what I want. I want to have few different methods like "callMainClass" to create "MainClass" objects  with different parameters.

Comment: create the object of class and then assign the parameters or call the methods

Comment: You should use `()` at the end like `this.mainClass = Abc.MainClass.callMainClass();` Then only it will create new object of `Abc.MainClass` and assign it to `this.mainClass` object.

Comment: @Karan - I tried that. The console shows an error that callMainClass is not a function...

Comment: @UllasHunka - if I do this by Object.create() I'll create two instances of that object: one by calling Object.create() and second after calling method 'callMainClass'. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually sequence of your implementation is incorrect. Update it as below.

```
Abc.MainClass = function(config) {

}

Abc.MainClass.callMainClass = function() {
    var config = null;
    return new Abc.MainClass(config);
}
```

Comment: Finally it works!!!! can't believe that. I would never noticed that and had no idea that the sequence is important in JS. Thank you!